# How is python importing a package in Docker without installing it in the container first?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have a new developer on our team and asked her to build a simple proof of concept of a Python client for an Apache Pulsar cluster in Docker.

What's got me flummoxed is that no where did she include a some step to install python package requirements. Normally, I have always had a Dockerfile with a line like:

```
# Install pip requirements
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

She however, she just has a `docker-compose.yml` file that looks like:

```
version: "3"
services:
  pulsar:
    image: apachepulsar/pulsar:latest
    command: ["bin/pulsar", "standalone"]
    volumes:
      - ./modules:/app

  producer:
    image: apachepulsar/pulsar:latest
    volumes:
      - ./modules:/app
    command: ["python", "/app/producer.py"]
    depends_on:
      - pulsar

  consumer:
    image: apachepulsar/pulsar:latest
    command: ["python", "/app/consumer.py"]
    volumes:
      - ./modules:/app
    depends_on:
      - pulsar
```

There's no command anywhere to install packages. And yet she has a simple script where she imports `pulsar` a package to facilitate interacting with Apache Pulsar and it runs and behaves fine on my machine. See below for example:

```
#!python
import pulsar

print('------ consumer output')
client = pulsar.Client('pulsar://pulsar:6650')
consumer = client.subscribe('my-topic', 'my-subscription')

while True:
    msg = consumer.receive()
    try:
        print("Received message '%s' id='%s'", msg.data().decode('utf-8'), msg.message_id(), flush=True)
        consumer.acknowledge(msg)
    except:
        consumer.negative_acknowledge(msg)

client.close()
```

How is this possible? I run a `docker system prune` thinking that maybe I had an image with the packages installed somehow? (Not sure that's even possible). But even after that the program still works.

Comment: I would imagine that a Docker image designed exactly to run and interact with Apache Pulsar (such as `apachepulsar/pulsar`) would *already have* such a trivial package installed... which is why you don't need to re-install it.

Comment: Kind of silly, but I didn't notice that she had used the `apachepulsar/pulsar` image for the python images. I'm sure you're right.

Answer (score 0):

All steps are here

https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/standalone-docker/

pip3 install pulsar-client